# C# console application word recognition

Tags: visual-studio-2013

It is necessary to create a program that will on the basis of input N car number plate ( eg . " KR 635 B " ) to count the number of vehicles from individual places . At the end of the program to print the amount of vehicles coming from a particular place , and the number of vehicles whose region is not recognized . Places that recognizes :
KR - Karlovac
BJ Bjelovar ...
I need a piece of code that identifies the first part of plate lets say: " KR "  , because when I use  if ( input = " KR " );
then recognizes only if I enter " KR " and not the entire registration .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You'll find a vast community of willing and helpful developers, but what you will not find are people willing to do your homework for you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question shows no effort.

Comment: I dont need whol program only that part that recognise first words "KR"...i only posted whol assigmet to show context

Comment: Great! What have you tried so far? :http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i tried google, but couldnt find what i need, i am no developer, sir but really ned help about that part

Comment: If you are not a developer, why are you asking for help on a developer problem? Also, we don't have enough information to help even if we wanted to. What are the recognized regions? Is this list of regions something that needs to be dynamic? Could regions be more than 2 characters? etc etc

Comment: If you are not a developer contract one to solve your development problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `StartsWith` method to check the beginning of a string. Example:

```
if (plate.StartsWith("KR")) {
  ...
}
```

If you are checking for muliple vales, you might want to get that part of the string as a separate string. You can get the first two characters:

```
string region = plate.Substring(0, 2);
```

Or the characters up to the first space:

```
string region = plate.Substring(0, plate.IndexOf(' '));
```

Comment: ty. that works perfectly , just a q can it be adapted to enter with  "kr" not only "KR"?

Comment: @Chupo: You can use the `ToLower` and `ToUpper` methods to get a string with the case altered.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bool again = true;
               //variable
               int bje = 0;
               int zgr = 0;
               int spt = 0;
               int vzn = 0;
               int npo = 0;

               //petlja za y/n

               while(again)
                {
                   // program unutar loopa
                Console.WriteLine("Unesite registarsku oznaku: ");


                string unos = Console.ReadLine();
                if (unos == "bj")
                    //
                    bje++;
                else if (unos == "zg")
                    //
                    zgr++;
                else if (unos == "sp")
                    //
                    spt++;
                else if (unos == "vz")
                    //
                    vzn++;
                else
                    npo++;


                Console.WriteLine("Bjelovar:  " + bje);
                Console.WriteLine("zagreb:    " + zgr);
                Console.WriteLine("split:     " + spt);
                Console.WriteLine("varazdin:  " + vzn);
                Console.WriteLine("Nepoznato: " + npo);

                   // za ponovan unos loop
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ponovni unos? (Da/Ne)");
                string YN = Console.ReadLine();

                while (YN != "Y" && YN != "N" )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong entry. Again? (Y/N)");
                    YN = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                if (YN == "n")
                {
                    again = false;

                }
                }
```

See i need those "if statments" changed for that word recognition and just done that is under the if statment.